# Broad Band LAN connection through existing 6 wire phone line ( no phone connected )

Tags: connection, lan, broadband

I have an (up to but never achieved ) 10 mb  broadband signal coming into my house along the telephone line. The modem then connects the broadband signal via a LAN connection and Wi-Fi signal to my computers and iPad.

My workshop desk  is 54 yards (approx. 50m) downhill  from the modem (part of a separate building) – too far to give a good direct signal. The inside  corner of the workshop (by a window) receives a weak signal.

I have a disconnected telephone cable consisting of 6 wires going from the house to the workshop.  The telephone is no longer used in the workshop - we use our mobile number for business calls. A broad band signal using the cable would not have to share with a phone.

What would be the most economic price/efficient way to get the broadband signal to the workshop?

I am writing in hope that since the telephone didn't need the six wires, an Ethernet connection might be similar and not need all the eight wires for a LAN connection.
In theory could use the telephone wire to pull an Ethernet cable trough the underground pipe but I doubt if the cable would survive the strain.

The broad band connection in the workshop does not have to have network facility.
My skill level is high enough to do house wiring, plumbing and gas fitting; so given any sound advice and a wiring diagram or instructions I can probably work out the rest  myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ethernet only needs 4 wires (to 100Mbps, [pins 4–5, 7–8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_twisted_pair)). If you want 1000Mbps you need all 8 wires.

But i don't think your current phone-wire is suitable to carry Ethernet signal (*you could try of course*). I believe you want to keep the WiFi/Network in house so the best option it to put in a new cable (Cat5e for 100Mbps, better Cat6 for future use) to your workshop (which you already considered).

For pulling a new cable through the pipe: if you have concerns about snapping you could pull another thin-cord (which would survive the strain) though the pipe (making sure it is really secure to the phone-wire), pulling out the phone-wire after which you would use that thin-cord to pull a new cat5e/cat6 cable. (How big/small is the pipe and does it make sharp corners? How was the original phone-wire pulled in the pipe?)

[Here](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-wire-your-house-with-cat5-or-cat6-ethernet-cable-480020760) is an article which shows you "How To Wire Your House with Cat5e or Cat6 Ethernet Cable". It has the necessary instructions you would need for rewiring.

Alternatively you could try another WiFi-router with a stronger antenna or/and putting the WiFi-router closer to the workshop if possible. There are also "repeaters" on the market which pick up the signal and transmit it. Is your current WiFi modem closest as you can get to your workshop? You could extend your current phone line somewhat and put the ADSL/WiFi-modem closer to the workshop. But it will depend on the signal quality of the original ADSL-line.  If it is poor quality, extending it might cause it to lose more speed.

Do you have a separate ADSL-modem and WiFi-router or is this an all-in-one device? If they are separate maybe you could put the WiFi-router closer to the workshop (within your house).

Another option is the possibility of using the powerline to the workshop. If an outlet in house is on the same circuit you could also use a DC powerline-adapter to extend your network. (The ethernet signal will be transferred over the power-line.) Like [these ones](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?categoryid=1657&model=TL-PA251KIT) (you need 2) but there are lots of others (you need the one compatible with your outlets). These could be more stable than a weak WiFi signal. Make sure you can return them if they don't work in your situation but i thought i would mention the possibility.

Comment: Thank you very much for  your comprehensive reply - I can’t see myself pulling down a cat6 cable. Because - as I have just remembered - when I put the original cable in I put it in the pipe before I laid the pipe down so there are too many turns causing too much fiction to pull the wire through in place – and no way could I dig it up. If the connection trough the phone doesn’t work (giving every thing a try) I shall purchases a signal relaying Wi-Fi router "repeater" and place it by the window in the workshop. Regards Paul

Comment: One thing i didn't mention yet the possibility of using the powerline to the workshop. If an outlet in house is **on the same circuit** you could also use a DC powerline adapter to extend your network. (The ethernet signal will be transferred over the power-line.) Like [these ones](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?categoryid=1657&model=TL-PA251KIT) but there are lots of others (you need the one for your outlets). These could be more stable than a weak WiFi signal. Make sure you can return them if they don't work in your situation but i thought i would mention the possibility.